# goquery BeforeHtml doesn't add element

Tags: go, goquery

I am trying to insert an html element before another html element using "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery". Unfortunately, the new element is not added

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"
    "strings"

    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
)

var html = `
<section>
    <article>
        <h2>Article 1</h2>
        <p>Text for article #1</p>
    </article>
    <article>
        <h2>Article 2</h2>
        <p>Text for article #2</p>
    </article>
</section>
`

func main() {
    qHtml, err := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(strings.NewReader(html))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    section := qHtml.Find(`section`)
    section.BeforeHtml(`<h1>Team Supreme</h1>`)

    goquery.Render(os.Stdout, section)
}
```

The same is true if I replace

```golang
section.BeforeHtml(`<h1>Team Supreme</h1>`)
```

with

```golang
section = section.BeforeHtml(`<h1>Team Supreme</h1>`)
```

Not sure what is the right way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

[`BeforeHtml`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery#Selection.BeforeHtml) is working as expected it is not visible since you are only rendering selected section tag and its content but the appended `h1` element is before it to make appended `h1` tag visible you have to update below line

```golang
goquery.Render(os.Stdout, section)
```

To

```golang
goquery.Render(os.Stdout, qHtml.Selection)
```